# Automatically assign DNS

Tags: network, dns

How do I ensure that the DNS is being set by the network?

On `Windows` I would check here and make sure that `Obtain DNS server address automatically` was selected:

[image: DNS]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Open System Preferences and click the Network icon.

[image: Screen shot of System Preferences]

Select your network in the list on the left, and make sure that it says "Using DHCP" in the drop-down list after "Configure IPv4:"

[image: Screen shot of Network Settings]

If you've made any changes, click the "Apply" button and then the "Show All" button to make sure everything is saved.

Comment: Do what @Lizzan said, then click the "Apply" button then the "Show All" button to make sure everything is saved.

Comment: Thanks @DanijelJ - I added your comment to the answer to keep it all together.